# Broken pipe in socket python

Tags: python, sockets, thermal-printer

i'm using this library in order to print to thermal printers via ethernet: https://github.com/Simonefardella/escposprinter

But, when i'll launch a lot of prints, after a while i'm getting error 32 Broken Pipe.

I don't know why, and i really need a solution, because, if i'll launch from two different ip's two prints everything stop working and i have to relaunch the print command...

I don't know why, there is something related with the socket?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `Broken Pipe error` because one of your end tries to send data to an already closed connection, in this case the printer.

Most probably the socket is closed after a sometime, or for a request it ends with a timeout which results in a closed connection.

What are you saying is that only after a while you get this error. Try to re-connect when you get `[Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

Comment: Ok, understood, but it's strange...how i can prevent the closing of the socket?
There are any solution differently from re-opening the connection?
So, as i understand it, the first printing process close the socket and when i try to send a new print to the printer it try to reuse the socket but it's already closed? right?

Comment: That's right. I don't think that there is much to do to keep the socket connection alive; only if the printer has something for this. Programming with sockets it's like having a contract between 2 parts: 1 doesn't respect it, if fails on the other part.
As not having any depths of the code or the printer API, I would go on re-connecting the socket.